# Sharing common Spring Boot configuration between projects

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration, java-8, spring-test

The app I'm working on has a maven dependency on a common module containing a dozen `spring-boot` `@Configuration` beans specifying datasources, LDAP contexts, security modules, property sources etc which I often want to suppress.

My app and this common module are part of a `spring-boot` `maven` multi-module project. My sub-project needs about 6 of the 12 configuration beans.

I have got quite a long way using `@Import` and `@SpringBootApplication#exclude` and `@ImportAutoConfiguration`:

```
@Import({PropertySpringConfig.class,
        LdapConfig.class,
        SecurityConfig.class,
        JpaDataConfiguration.class,
        RestConfiguration.class,
        WebConfigurer.class})
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {
        RefDataSourceConfig.class,
        ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration.class,
        CamelAutoConfiguration.class,
        ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration.class})
public class MyRestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyRestApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

and a test configuration bean that all my JPA tests import (I have others, e.g. for REST tests):

```
@Configuration
@OverrideAutoConfiguration(enabled = false)
@ImportAutoConfiguration(value = {
        CacheAutoConfiguration.class,
        JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class,
        DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
        DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class,
        HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
        TransactionAutoConfiguration.class,
        TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration.class,
        TestEntityManagerAutoConfiguration.class })
public class TestJpaConfiguration {}
```

The whole codebase was set up with Spring 1.3.x. I upgraded it to Spring 1.4.x.

Take for example one of the datasources, a configuration bean in the shared dependency - I don't need it, and it prevents Spring Boot autoconfiguration because it's marked with `@Primary` (possibly unnecessarily).

I don't want Spring Boot in my sub-project to see it when it runs autoconfiguration, but how do I share it from the common module with the other Spring Boot sub-projects that do need it?

1. I could split it out into its own maven project and only have it as a dependency in the sub-projects that needed it. But there are 11 other similar configuration beans! It could be seen as overkill although I like this approach - but I have 5 colleauges to convince.
2. I can just struggle on using `@SpringBootApplication#excludes` for the code and `@ImportAutoConfiguration` for the tests - but then I miss out on the Spring Boot benefits like `@DataJpaTest` or `@JsonTest` test slices
3. I could repeat the configuration beans in each project where they are needed - a bit of cut & paste - but I like this option the least.
4. Is there a 4?

Comment: You could pepper your configuration classes with `@ConditionalXXXX` annotations to make sure they're only enabled/provide beans when certain conditions are met (in your client app) like properties enabled, dependencies present, etc. I think it will make it much easier to control which configurations are loaded in your app. Also having `@Primary` annotated beans in dependency modules is not helping.

Comment: That's an idea that I need to look into but it would also make the code noisier. And add to that all the `@SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaAutowiringInspection")` annotations I have to mask the Intellij errors because its Spring Boot facet can't keep up.

Comment: What I don't understand is the link with you having the need to filter 6 out of the 12 configuration classes and messing around with auto-configuration excludes. These are two totally separate issue to me. Can you clarify that?

Comment: My messing-around with auto-configuration excludes is the only way that I have found so far to suppress the configurations I don't want. It works - I don't get the unwanted datasource, I don't get the unwanted security. How would you prevent spring boot from finding and auto-configuring them?

Comment: What I am trying to say is that you have two different problems mixed in one question so it makes it quite hard to give you a satisfactory answer. Auto-configuration backs off when it detects beans of your own. Looks like what you've done is extreme or we did something wrong in boot.

Comment: I guess the current edited question title is better? I wish to ignore some of the 12 common `@Config` beans in tests to reduce unnecessary load and in some cases so that autoconfiguration sets up my resources instead.

Comment: After doing loads of debugging of the spring context setting itself up, I've decided that the Spring context filtering mechanism in the classpath scanner is so complex it's not worth the time trying to understand it, I'm just going to give up using includes, excludes, imports and all that, and concentrate on cleaning up my projects and subprojects and making sure I only have the dependencies I need in the projects where I need them, so that Spring Boot automatically only finds what I want.